# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, openjpa

I am creating a small desktop application in Intellij Idea 13, using Maven and OpeJPA.  I run the application and this open ok, but when I search a `cliente` into the database with the application, the exception stack is launched.

This is the configuration in the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="sacPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>cl.im.sac.Model.Cliente</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sac"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="sac-root" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="sac.root.1844" />

            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                      value="buildSchema(SchemaAction='add,OpenJPATables=true',ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=WARN, Tool=INFO, SQL=ERROR"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties"
                      value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary"/>
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider" value="sjvm"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is de `Cliente` class and `ClienteDao` class

```
@Table(name = "cliente", catalog = "sac")
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidoPaterno;
    private String apellidoMaterno;
    private String sexo;
    private String run;
    private String direccion;
    private String comuna;
    private Date fechaIngreso;
    private int telefono;
    private int movil;
    private String email;
    private String usuario;
    private String pass;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Producto> productos;

   /** METHODS **/

}
```

ClienteDao Class

```
public class ClienteDao {

    private static EntityManager entityManager = Persistencia.getEntityManager();

    public static Cliente find(Long id){
        return entityManager.find(Cliente.class,id);
    }

    public static Cliente findByRUN(String rn){
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select c from Cliente c where c.run=:run");
        q.setParameter("run",rn);
        if(!q.getResultList().isEmpty()){
            List c= q.getResultList();
            return (Cliente) c.get(0);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Persistence Class

```
public class Persistencia {

    private static EntityManager entityManager;

    static{
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sacPU");
        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

Exception stack

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cl.im.sac.Dao.ClienteDao.<clinit>(ClienteDao.java:17)
    at cl.im.sac.UI.Interfaz$1.actionPerformed(Interfaz.java:87)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.redefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:96)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:176)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at cl.im.sac.Dao.Persistencia.<clinit>(Persistencia.java:16)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.redefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:85)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
```

Please, don't use that property. Set it back to `unsupported`, or remove it all together. You need to either enhance at build time, or use the -javaagent.

[OpenJPA Entity Enhancement](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html)

Comment: I set it back to `unsupported`, but the error change, `Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent:` how use the -javaagent?

Comment: The link I posted documents how to enhance your Entities properly.